# See solid background instead of slant/diagnal line pattern in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, difftool

[Please check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9xb1.jpg)

Replace the pattern on right side with a plain background

Comment: the same image but a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73814958/9938317), is your screen capture tool still broken

Comment: @rioV8 I took a pic of it on my phone